# OpenCart 3 nginx config for multi language

Tags: nginx, opencart, opencart-3

I have a config

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @opencart;
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
            expires     max;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return  404;
            }

            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9002;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location @opencart {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }
```

it works fine, but I am want to add multi-language support from URL like:

```
location /en {
  rewrite ^/en/([^?]*) /index.php?_route_=$1&lang=en break;
}

location /es {
  rewrite ^/es/([^?]*) /index.php?_route_=$1&lang=es break;
}
```

Get language as the first URL param, and put it as get parameter `&lang=es` to index.php. 
How correctly do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that multilingual postfix through nginx (or even apache) configs. There are a lot of connections and routing around the main HTTP_SERVER (or HTTPS_SERVER) global constant. Maximum what will you get - 301 redirect on every page loading. Which is unacceptable for search engines.

I suggest you to try tree different ways to solve this tusk:

1. Rewrite *system/library/url.php* or
   *catalog/controller/startup/startup.php*. Don't have the exact code, but if you are familiar to php - the routing of URL you can find in
   these files. Nice manual here
   [How to set language through url in opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588719/how-to-set-language-through-url-in-opencart)
2. Use some free or paid modules from marketplace by query "language code in url".
3. If You are using SEO URL - there are multilingual urls on each product, category etc. You don't need postfix with these, all URLs could multilingual and unique.
   [image]
   If you don't have these functions - just download it from here, it's free https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=32788