# Setting language through url in opencart disable choosing language from top of the page

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

Iam using opencart version 3.0.3.2. I am trying to enter a specific page in the store with specific language using URL link. My store have English and Arabic languages, and for example i want to go to login page in arabic by only giving the URL link to someone.
I found a solution to do this in this question.
[How to set language through url in opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588719/how-to-set-language-through-url-in-opencart)
by adding at the end of the URL '&lng=ar' or '&lng=en' i can specify the language. However, this is only working well in home page, but if i use it in the login page for example it will cause another probelm.
I have tried this in **login page** and the language **did actually changed but then when i try to change the language again from the drop down language menu from the top of the page it wont changed** unless i click away to another page then i can change the language from the top, i dont know why maybe this new link causing problem or whatever. Also, this solution is before two years not the same version.
I need to use this for login and register page if any one can help me. Thanks in advance.